# Google Big query for transposing data from rows to columns

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Here is the sample data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4uH7.png)

Expected Output (respective answer only)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DafA9.png)

Comment: use pivot function.

Comment: sample pivot article: https://towardsdatascience.com/pivot-in-bigquery-4eefde28b3be